# Запустить функцию из внешнего, подключаемого скрипта

Tags: javascript, события

Подключаю внешнее API. Там есть функция - обработчик события. Я знаю ее название. Знаю на каком элементе она срабатывает. 
Как мне запустить этот обработчик еще и на своем элементе?
Пробовал `button.addEventListener('click', a)`, но ничего не получилось: `a is not defined`.

UpDate:
Мне кажется, что я нашел свой "камень преткновения" - нужная мне функция спрятана в другой функции. Но я все равно не знаю, как ее оттуда достать.
Упрощенный код внешнего скрипта:

```
window.onload = function() {
    "use strict";
    var r = document.createElement("select");
    r.setAttribute("name", "cities"),
    r.setAttribute("onchange", "OneFunc.onCityChange(this.value)");
 }();
var  OneFunc= function() {
    "use strict";
  function a() {
        console.log("Необходимая функция");
    }
   var  E = document.getElementById("close-button");

    return 
    E.addEventListener("click", function() {
        a()
    }),
    {
     oncityChange: l,            
    }

}();
```

Comment: Добавь код...  Тут ясновидящих нет...

Comment: Какой код добавить и зачем он для данного вопроса? Вопрос же не в конкретном коде.

Comment: Код нужен, так как первые четыре предложения вопроса, могли бы быть понятно по отдельности, но, к сожалению, вместе только запутывают

Comment: @DanielKhoroshko, внес изменения

Comment: Внешнее апи обычно не спрятано внутри области видимости модуля

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, к сожалению, в моем случае это правило не работает. Может быть можно вытащить список обработчиков на конкретном элементе и повесить их на другой?

Comment: А что под капотом покажите

Comment: Что надо вызвать

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, упрощенный код скрипта есть в вопросе. Функция `a`

Comment: Можно самому создать и послать этому компоненту событие

Comment: Скопировать тело обработчика в свой код

Comment: Вызвать обработчик руками

Comment: Зависит от содержимого функции a

Comment: А это задача возникла в проекте который планируете долго поддерживать? Если да, тогда не надо ее решать таким образом. Этим самым вы загоняете проект в очень нехорошую яму. Лучше найти другую библиотеку, либо реализовать нужный функционал заново.

Comment: Кстати, если это популярная библиотека, типа jQuery.UI, тогда возможно будет толк если подойти к задаче с другой стороны. Задайте другой вопрос, в котором опишите свою задачу и назовите библиотеку, с помощью которой ее хотели решить, но пришли к описываемой здесь сложности. Просто есть вероятность что вы пытаетесь решить задачу немного не  с того конца [ошибка молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/Что-такое-Ошибка-молотка-или-Ошибка-xy).

Comment: В примере код обработчика не имеет замыканий на область видимости

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, @Uranus, спасибо за комментарии, благодаря им я подошел к проблеме с другой стороны и решил ее. Т.к. я пытался воссоздать обработчик события, зная на каком элементе он срабатывает - я решил просто вызвать это событие на этом элементе  с помощью `elem.dispatchEvent`.

Comment: Пожалуйста это я и имел в вижу когда писал что можно самому создать событие и послать компоненту

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, для таких "программистов" как я - это было не явно. И поэтому, мне показалось, что Вы имеете ввиду `Ctrl+c` `Ctrl+v` ))